# rest framework csrf для GET запросов

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, csrf

Добрый день! Описываю на сайте api с помощью **rest framework**. Есть страница со списком новостей

> /api/v1/news/

как запретить к ней доступ если в куках отсутствует **csrftoken**?

```
class NewsCreateAPIView(CreateAPIView):
    queryset = News.objects.all()
    serializer_class = NewsCreateUpdateSerializer
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        serializer.save(user=self.request.user)
```

Comment: для `POST` запроса это и так будет работать, зачем ограничивать для `GET`?

Comment: Чтобы боты не ходили, или кто нибудь не обращался к api с другого сервера

Comment: ботов можно запретить в `robots.txt`, а обращение к апи в переменной `ALLOWED_HOSTS`, которая в сетингах. Но если сильно нужно то можно написать кастомный пермишен, наследуясь от `BasePermission` и там перегрузить `has_permission`. В доках рест фреймворка есть пример